# Post method doesn't work with html form in MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, post

Why is that the `$.post()` method doesn't work ? I press the button but it doesn't post to `EditClassLessonHour`.

Here is the View Code:

```
<div class="jumbotron">

    <form id="editClassLessonHour">

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)

        <span> Classes &nbsp;: </span>
        <select name="classes" id="classes">
            @foreach (var item in ViewBag.classes as List<SelectListItem>)
            {
                <option value="@item.Value">@item.Text</option>
            }
        </select>
        <br /><br />

        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon" name="lessons" id="lessons">Lessons : </span>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.LessonName, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["lesson"], new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Lesson", aria_describedby = "txtClassNumber" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LessonName)
        </div>
        <br />

        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon" name="hours" id="hours">Hour : </span>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Hour, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["hour"], new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Lesson", aria_describedby = "txtClassNumber" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Hour)
        </div>
        <br />

        <input type="button" value="Kaydet" id="kaydet" class="btn btn-success" onclick="post(); " />

    </form>
    <br />
</div>

<script>
    $.post('/ClassLessonHour/EditClassLessonHour',{
        classId: $('#classes').val(),
        lessonId: $('#lessons').val(),
        hourId: $('#hours').val()
    }, function (result) {
        $('#message').html(result.message);
    });
</script>
```

Here is Controller Code

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditClassLessonHour(int classId, int lessonId, int hourId)
{

}
```

What can I do? I want that when I press the button, the form should be posted to the Controller.

Comment: "doesn't work" how? Have you checked your browser console for errors? And the network tab to see if any request is made, and if so, what the response was? Sounds like you haven't actually tried to debug it. "doesn't work" is what the user would tell you. As a programmer you can do more investigation than that.

Comment: But anyway, it's immediately obvious from the code that the $.post command will be run the moment that script tag is loaded into the page. There's nothing to tie it to the button click event at all. Your "onclick" references a "post()" function which doesn't exist in your code. Also you should use unobtrusive event handlers instead of inline ones, for better readability and maintainability. Any simple jQuery tutorial will show you how to handle a click event and then execute some code as a result.

Answer (score 2):

```
onclick="post();"
```

You don't *have* a function called `post`.  You don't have any function at all.  You're just executing an AJAX POST request as soon as the page loads.

Remove that `onclick` attribute entirely and bind your AJAX call to the button's click event.  Something like this:

```
$(function () {
    $('#kaydet').on('click', function () {
        $.post('/ClassLessonHour/EditClassLessonHour',{
            classId: $('#classes').val(),
            lessonId: $('#lessons').val(),
            hourId: $('#hours').val()
        }, function (result) {
            $('#message').html(result.message);
        });
    });
});
```

---

Though it seems likely that there are *more* problems here.  For example, this:

```
$('#lessons').val()
```

The `id="lessons"` element is a `<span>`, which doesn't *have* a "value".  You want to target the `<select>` being generated by `@Html.DropDownListFor`, not the `<span>` that's near it.  Examine your HTML in the browser to see what is being generated by that server-side code.  It may have an `id` or `name` that you can use in your jQuery selector.  (This same problem applies to your `#hours` element as well.)

Comment: "Remove that onclick", id="lessons" is moved to in div and $(function () { ... is added but it doesn't work again

Comment: @Embabu: It's not clear at all what you're trying to describe in that comment.  If you have updated code, include it in the question.  Also include a specific description of the problem and what debugging you have done.

Comment: `{
            classId: $('#classes').val(),
            lessonId: $('#lessons').val(),
            hourId: $('#hours').val()
        }` could be replaced with simply `$("#editClassLessonHour").serialize()` for greater brevity and maintainability (although arguably the redundant HiddenFor control should be removed in that case, to avoid posting it back unnecessarily). It will just automatically create post variables from the contents of the form controls.

Comment: @ADyson: True.  Though they may also need to modify the signature of the target action method if serialization changes the keys.  Ideally that should be a model anyway, and ideally the same one (or very similar) to the one used to populate the form in the first place.

Comment: @David true. I hadn't noticed the names/keys are different. But yes it should all be done using a viewmodel. I suspect OP hasn't grasped all of the concepts of MVC yet otherwise it would be done like that already. I think the ID/name of the `<selects>` will be LessonName and Hour - MVC normally uses the name of the model property by default.